# how can i escape the colon from my json object

Tags: json

my json object is `{"value":"3:Low:2:Med","fieldName":"multiple_priority"}`

here i am getting output as

```
                    3
                    low
                    2
                    med
```

but, i need the output as

```
3:low
2:med
```

how can i get it?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to post your javascript code. A JSON object has no output itself. It's the code manipulating it.

Comment: what json parser are you using?

Comment: Are you doing a split upon `:` to achieve your current output? there's nothing to distinguish the colon in `Low:2` from the one in `2:Med`, say. as others have pointed out, it is your implementation, and not your JSON that is mainly at fault here, but if you can, you probably want to change your JSON representation to something like `{"value":[{"id":3,"value":"Low"},{"id":2,"value":"Med"}],"fieldName":"multiple_priority"}`

Answer (score 0):

If 'value' always have the same structure, you can use this:

```
var a = {"value":"3:Low:2:Med","fieldName":"multiple_priority"};
eval("var b = " + a['value'].replace(/(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)/, "{$1:'$2',$3:'$4'}"));
b[3]; // Low
b[2]; // Med
```